# Problem with react routes in Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

I just deployed my react web app with azure, It deploys correctly but i cant access the routes, ex. "`https://domain.azurewebsites.net/api/login`", I get this error:

```
message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
data: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."
```

Locally it works perfectly with `http://localhost:3001/api/login`, nonetheless i cant seem to make it work online. Im using node.js and Github deployment, this is my current web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This an example of one route: `router.post("/login", authController.login);` And my index.js looks like this:

```
...code
// //Middlewares
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());


// //Rutas
const authRoutes = require("./build/routes/authRoutes")
const authRoutesAPP = require("./build/routes/authRoutesAPP")
app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/app', authRoutesAPP);

//Servidor
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server on port', app.get('port'))
})
```

Can anyone give me an advice? Its my first time deploying a web app.

I tried changing the web.config, and also removing the `/api` part before the route, but i also get an error.

Comment: Azure Static Web Apps in the [staticwebapp.config.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes)

Comment: I'll give a few sample examples of how to work with how to use the route.

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#azure) for Azure for what needs to be setup/configured to handle your API backend requests.

Answer (score 0):

- Enable CORS in Portal with Azure CLI liked below:

```
az resource update --name web --resource-group <group-name> \
  --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type config \
  --parent sites/<app-name> --set properties.cors.supportCredentials=true
```

- Add the settings `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true`

```js
export  default  function  App() {
return (
<Router>
<div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
</li>
<li>
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
</li>
<li>
<Link to="/users">Users</Link>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<Switch>
<Route path="/about">
<About />
</Route>
<Route path="/users">
<Users />
</Route>
<Route path="/">
<Home />
</Route>
</Switch>
</div>
</Router>
);
}
function  Home() {
return <h2>Home</h2>;
}
function  About() {
return <h2>About</h2>;
}
function  Users() {
return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

**web.config**:

```java
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule  name="React Routes"  stopProcessing="true">
<match  url=".*"  />
<conditions  logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add  input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"  matchType="IsFile"  negate="true"  />
<add  input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"  matchType="IsDirectory"  negate="true"  />
<add  input="{REQUEST_URI}"  pattern="^/(api)"  negate="true"  />
</conditions>
<action  type="Rewrite"  url="/"  />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
<staticContent>
```

- In [Local](https://i.imgur.com/rNuZNKB.png) and [Azure](https://i.imgur.com/c0ydYAq.png) [portal](https://i.imgur.com/bGt85j5.png).
- Another method is staticwebapp.confige [Statc Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes) with [rotting rules](https://medium.com/@elnoor/react-client-side-routing-in-azure-static-web-app-299c8ba96fb8#:%7E:text=Once%20a%20static%20app%20is%20deployed%20in%20an,route%20based%20on%20rules%20set%20in%20those%20files.) and deploy in[Azure Static Web  App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes) Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66110316/azure-static-app-route-configuration-with-react-router) for  more details .